# PHP get one row from an array based on a variables value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

If i create an array from results returned in a mysqli query is there a way to select and use only one specific row from the array?

```
$info= array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $info[] = array(  
        'id' => $row['id'],  
        'location' => $row['location']
    );  
}
```

How would i go about displaying only a single row from this array where the id equals a variable like $id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop you could just do something like:

```
if ($id == $row['id']) {
    $info[] = $row;
}
```

However it would make more sense to me to just update your query.

```
SELECT cols FROM t1 WHERE id = :id
```

Using `$id` as a parameter.

Comment: Im using the array result in a different while loop using 

if(in_array)

So i need all the results and not just the one the query would return. That part of my code works fine ill try your suggestion thanks.